# codeigniter redirect function puts ? between base_url and controller/function

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, redirect

I made a login script to access another controller so other people can't see that.

now I have a redirect function in my controller that redirects to another controller.

now when I redirect it works fine, but it puts a ? between my base_url and the controller like this:

http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/?/member/index

How do I solve that?

My home controller function:

```
public function process(){
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->login_model->validate();
    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index($msg);
    }else{
        // If user did validate, 
        // Send them to members area
        redirect('/member/index');
    }        
}
```

Does it have to do with my .htaccess file?

It looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^LoginTut.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by disabling query_strings like so:

From:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

To:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

In my Config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

use `redirect('member/index')`  insted of `redirect('/member/index')`;

Answer (score 0):

Change your htaccess to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^LoginTut.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

so that url are resolved to `index.php/controller` instead of `index.php?/controller`

Comment: Would you mind being more detailed instead of just being rude?